# Eclipse: add a run configuration in a makefile project

Tags: c++, eclipse, makefile

I have an Eclipse project that builds a library, with my own build script (that basically sets some variables, then calls a Makefile). I have set the Build Configuration to run this script, everything is OK: I can compile by just clicking on the *Build* button.

Now, I would like to test some parts of this lib. In the **same** project, I have created a C++ source file, with a little `main()`. I would like to create a run configuration to execute this small test program, but Eclipse tells me that "the binary does not exist" (of course, since I want to build it...).

What is the solution ?

Comment: Did you follow all steps as outlined [**here**](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~anderson/UsingEclipseCPP/) ?

Comment: Yes, thanks, but I think that my problem comes from the fact I need two build configurations: one that builds the lib, the other that build the executable. That's what I want to do (I suppose...)

Comment: Svp, communiquer en anglais sur SO. Probably Eclipse is confused what it should compile. [**Take a look at this tutorial**](https://tayefeh.wordpress.com/2009/07/06/creating-and-using-a-c-shared-library-with-eclipse-cdt-galileo-and-gnu-c-compiler-and-linker/) and at [**this video**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MnlknEMjjGw).

Comment: Yes, sorry, your name let me think you were French ;) I've edited my previous comment. I watch your video and tell you if it's ok.

Comment: Ok, in both cases, they create two projects: one for the lib, one for the test. That's I wanted to avoid, but it seems it is not easy or possible... Thanks for your help

Comment: Pas de problème. I guess that's indeed the only way to do it in Eclipse. Good luck!